# Array of classes. Stack or heap?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
class temp;

temp *t;

void foo() { temp foo2; t[1] = foo2; }

int main() { 
    t = new temp[100];
    foo();
    //t[1] is still in memory?
}
```

- **If i want an array of classes like this, am i going to have to use
  pointer to pointer?** (and use 'new'
  on each element in the array) E.G:
  `temp **t;`
- if i want to make an
  array of 100 ptr to ptr i have todo
  `temp **t = new temp[100][1];` **is
  there a better way to do that without
  4 square brackets?**

Comment: A *rule of thumb* for allocating quantities of object is:  small quantities in local storage, large quantities in dynamic memory.  Huge quantities in external memory (disk drive, memory mapped, OS specific).  If you don't want the headache of managing object deletions, use a *smart pointer* (search for Boost Smart_Ptr).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code:

```
t = new temp[100];
```

constructs an array 100 objects of type temp. A safer way to do the same thing is:

```
std::vector <temp> t(100);
```

which absolves you of ever having to call delete[] on the array.

Answer (score 4):

Try to avoid the new stuff at all until you exactly know what you are doing.

```
std::vector<temp> t(100);
```

will do the job in a perfect manner. You still can access it using [] operator and like in your solution.

```
temp foo2; t[1] = foo2;
```

will call the assignment operator of the temp class.
use & for passing the variable to a function.

```
void foo1(std::vector<temp>& lt)
{
}

void foo2(temp& lt)
{
}

foo1(t);
foo2(t[1]);
```

Comment: "will call the copy constructor of temp class"  actually, your code uses the assignment operator, not the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I support the other's suggestions to avoid new and use std::vector instead. std::vector saves many headaches caused by pointers and arrays. Arrays are very much a C solution, not a C++ solution.

To answer your question: you do not need a pointer-to-pointer type here. The reason is that arrays are naturally addressed by pointer.

When you say `t = new temp[100];` two things happen:

- A new array is allocated from the free store (or 'heap')
- `t` is set to point to the new array's first element.

When you use the `p[i]` operator, it is actually syntactic sugar for `*(p + i)`. For example:

- `t[0]` is equivalent to `*(t + 0)` which is just `*t`, or the element that `t` points at: the first element of the array.
- `t[1]` is equivalent to `*(t + 1)`. Since `t` is a pointer to the first element of the array, `t + 1` is a pointer to the element one place beyond the first: the second element. So `*(t + 1)` gives you the second element.

Using this system, a `temp *` pointer can be used to refer to a whole array of `temp`, instead of just a single `temp` instance.

If you really want to learn about arrays and pointers, you could do worse than read chapter 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com). Note, however, that this is a C resource, not a C++ resource; this is because in C++, arrays are generally not used because you have a better feature available: std::vector. I strongly recommend you make learning about std::vector a higher priority than learning about pointers and arrays.